# Curious about char pointer as class member?

Tags: c++, char

I saw this in a class declaration and was curious what is means? I am thinking that is may be a way to declare that a char array will be a member but the size is not fixed and will take it as an argument but I am not sure.

```
char *flagstr(int);
```

Is this what it is?

Comment: You cannot possibly have seen this "in a class declaration".

Comment: Not sure why the downvoting (or close votes) makes sense here. This is a specific, succinct, apparently earnest programming question.

Comment: I'm almost be fooled by this *"new syntax"*. :P

Comment: ... Don't I feel silly right now... I mean it's obvious... Well, I am going to blame it on mixing all kinds of programming languages the last few weeks and ignore my sense :). Yeah, sorry guys.

Comment: In your defense, having the * attached to the function name is a little misleading. I'd have written it "char* flagstr".

Comment: That the asterisk is visibly attached to the function name rather than the type is a bit of a holdover from C where it's common practice to visually bind the asterisk with the variable or function name. Putting the asterisk next to the name as opposed to type represents how C/C++ parse things. However, C++ programmers tend to view the asterisk as part of the type; it makes much more sense this way. C++ programmers are much more likely to write `char* flagstr(int)` than `char *flagstr(int)`. But note well: the standards do say otherwise, largely thanks to backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not what it is.

When you see a declaration like this inside a class

```
char *flagstr(int);
```

it declares a member function called `flagstr` which takes one argument of type `int`, and returns a pointer to character.

You can tell that you are looking at a function declaration, because there is a pair of parentheses after the name. It may be confusing, because the parameter name is omitted (C++ syntax rules do not require programmers to specify names of parameters in declarations; moreover, you can omit names of unused parameters in function definitions). Here is the same declaration that should look familiar:

```
char *flagstr(int flagValue);
```

Comment: The words "optional parameter name" might be misleading to some one new too the language, as it might get conflated with an "optional parameter" (int i = 0).

Comment: @WillKrause You are right, this may sound misleading. I edited the answer to address this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a function declaration which takes an `int` as its input parameter and return type `char *`.

You're confused here mainly because you forget that, in a function declaration, input parameter names are not necessary (only their types are).